# Azure AD SSO = AADSTS50020 - multi-tenant, How do I allow external tenants to register to my app?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We have a SaaS app and we are integrating with azure ad sso with oauth2 (locally for now) using https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure (v2 common endpoint)

So far, you can log-in, new accounts are automatically registered(On our app, using tenant id to link them to an organizaton on our end)

The problem? I'm trying make it multi-tenant, so I've created another azure account and I don't know how to register to the application, it tells me to create the user as an external user but I would like it to be automated if possible than having to add users to our app (i.e. I was hoping our app can be registered to an external AD).

This is what I get right now when I try to login with the new user coming from an external Azure AD.

`AADSTS50020: User account '*****@gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant '***' and cannot access the application '***-**-**-**-***' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.`

Are adding external users to our main active directory the only way, and if so, is there a simple way to automate the process as much as possible (i.e. add every user from an existing AD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure B2B collaboration let you share your organization applications with guest users from any other organization, so, if user is from a any other organization or tenant, for example tenant A and trying to login to tenant B, then you would need to add the user from tenant A to tenant B as a guest user. Refer to the link [What is guest user access in Azure Active Directory B2B?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/what-is-b2b).
Please refer to [Bulk invite Azure AD B2B collaboration users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-tutorial-bulk-invite) to invite multiple guest users to your organization at the same time using PowerShell.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to doing this yet, as the first draft will be for a single tenant, but based on research this seems to be the way to go so accepting this answer